# Devextreme push notification

Tags: notifications, push-notification, devexpress, push, devextreme

I'm new at **DevExpress**. I'm developing a mobile application in Devextreme multi channel application.

I have a **mssql** database and this database is connected with **WCF ODataService** to mobile application. When is added an item to mssql, The notification must be pushed. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you use **DataSource** and **ODataStore** to access your OData service. If you add an item using **ODataStore.insert()** method, you can show notification within the ODataStore **inserted** event handler

```
var odataStore = new DevExpress.data.ODataStore({
    url: "http://sampleservices.devexpress.com/Northwind.svc/Products",
    key: "ProductID",
    keyType: "Guid",
    onInserted: function(){
        DevExpress.ui.notify("Item inserted");
    }
});
```

or within a **done** callback of the **insert()** method

```
odataStore.insert({
    ProductName: 'Some name',
    CategoryID: 1,
    . . .
}).done(function(){
    DevExpress.ui.notify("Item inserted");
})
```

See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/my1avL7m/).

You can also find useful information on working with data in DevExtreme applications in [this guide](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Guide/Data_Layer/Data_Layer).

Comment: Thanks Victor,but I am asked how I can do push notification in Devextreme mobile application

Comment: Unfortunately, DevExtreme does provide this functionality. I think you need to use the appropriate [PhoneGap](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin) plugin. See [this tutorial](http://devgirl.org/2013/07/17/tutorial-implement-push-notifications-in-your-phonegap-application/).

Comment: Have you looked at something like Signal-R to push data from the service to the client (DevExtreme app)?